# BufferedImage produces black output

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface

BufferedImage for some reason produces black output when I write scaled Image, however Image scales it correctly. I assume here are some problems with painting components. Thank you!

Comment: is it supposed to be transparent? if so .jpg files dont have transparency, you have to use .png

Comment: Of course not, this is a normal RGB image, however it does not write to Imagebuffer for some reason.

Comment: oh, im just thought you meant that its showing up black, transparency in .jpg file would be black

Comment: @JRowan thanks for your reply. WHEN BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB produces black AND THEN BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB, orange color image.

Comment: *"BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB, orange color image."*  Are you still saving as JPEG?  Saving an `ARGB` image as JPEG will cause unpredictable results - don't do it!

Comment: Did you miss the part where I mentioned ***don't do it***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

If putting a PNG or GIF with transparency over it, the transparent parts will become black.  It should be:

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

But then, I recommend:

- Only save as JPEG if the original image was JPEG
- Not using an `ImageIcon` to load an `Image`, instead use `ImageIO` to load a `BufferedImage`.
- Use the buffered image `getType()` as the parameter instead of `BufferedImage.TYPE_..`
- Avoid `getScaledInstance(..)` [like the plague](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html), but if using it, specify `Image.SCALE_SMOOTH`.